# Civicrm Entity & Drupal 8

Tags: civicrm-entity, drupal-8

I have begun working on structuring a franchise type educational site and we are going with CiviCRM and Drupal.  However, we wanted to go with drupal 8 since we are starting fresh with a complete overhaul.

The reason I am writing, is I came across the civicrm Entity module, and from descriptions looks very promising to connect the needs of civi and our Drupal aspects of the project.  I wanted to ask though, how far along is that 8.x version? And is it ok to use?.... we are having some issue currently....

I did install the dev module that is up on https://www.drupal.org/project/civicrm_entity , however, I think something isn’t working as while I can place a civi field in a content type as entity reference, and I can add content and the reference loads in the form and can be selected, once saved however, all it shows is a “restricted access” text with (id) in the field, and when viewing published version that content item that field/reference does not show.

Also, I do not see the CiviCRM Entity types under the Drupal STRUCTURE admin area, but from some of the screen shots in blog documentation I saw this should be there for management options too….

We currently have all other modules and civi working with drupal 8, and this is our last critical piece of the puzzle.  Unfortunately, while I am comfortable working with drupal, I do not have a code background so couldn’t dig into this.

Is there more to activating this module than doing through main drupal admin panel, or maybe it should have been done via composer? Any insight anyone can provide would be MUCH appreciated on helping me getting civi Entity going & connected!

Comment: The 8.x-3.x-dev version of the module has recently had some major development committed. You might try it out again.

Answer (score 4):

There is still work to be done to get this firing fully - and you many need to reach out to some of the [Partners](https://chat.civicrm.org/civicrm/channels/civicrm-entity) to help get things working sufficiently for your scenario. There are a number that have done a bunch of work in this area.

There are some other Drupal tools that aren't fully firing with civicrm, ones that we use in pretty much every development as they are so helpful in bending the laws of the civi universe - eg Webform_civicrm and Views integration.

There has been a recent push on the webform side of things, and the plan for Views is to step fully in to tieing it in with Civicrm_entity.

You may find you want to join both https://chat.civicrm.org/civicrm/channels/civicrm-entity and https://chat.civicrm.org/civicrm/channels/drupal which is where most of the active discussions are taking place.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, and I will likely reach out to someone, and check out the channels you mentioned.  However, any updates on time expectations generally speaking on the things you mentioned?  I know the whole Drupal 8 thing seems to be lagging along generally, but we really don't want to make a switch in the near future from 7 since we are building from the ground up on this project. thanks for your work!

Comment: Mark (jackrabbithanna) Hanna is currently the most active civi entity developer. We (Fuzion) did a lot of the ground work for the D7 project. I don't quite follow "we really don't want to make a switch in the near future from 7" maybe you missed a double negative (eg did you mean switch back to d7?)? I read the OP that you are planning to build this in D8 - so am confused by the d7 mention

Comment: This is a correct answer. We've had a major contributor get the ball rolling for CiviCRM Entity for D8, but I really don't consider it even in an alpha state. Although peter, Skvare, myself and others have invested both personal and company resources into its development over the years, it was always people paying for features which really pushed it to what it is today. Open source is free like kittens, not free like beer, which means somebody has to pay to feed the developers. it WILL come in time, but investors can speed the process significantly.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, it is nice to know where things are more, and I totally understand circumstance.  I wish our little non-profit could help speed things along more, but currently I am volunteering myself to figure this out, ha.  Will probably backtrack a little then, and use Drupal 7 since we really need civi and drupal talking nicely so we can use the data more, and obviously the civi Entity seems best suited for that and a critical component.  Best wishes in your work!

Comment: Not a bad idea, and I just read that the Drupal.org will likely be supporting Drupal 7 until 2021 or 2022 https://www.thirdandgrove.com/long-road-drupal-9